# GCM notification is not getting on android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have implement GCM Notification in android.I got registration id form android but when I send registarion id to GCM Server from .net web server.we got response like that

```
{
StatusCode: 200
Data: "id=0:1445015279022584%e375dde966d6cf16"
Status: "Success"
Message: ""
}
```

But notification is not getting on android device.I am write code on android to receive notification like

```
if(intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"))

        {

            final   String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id"); 

            Constant.setApplicationPreferences(context, "REGISTRAION_ID", registration);
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) 
        {

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            //write here extra code

}
```

So please tell me it is android side issue or server side.Please suggest and share use able link that how to fix this issue.

Comment: same problem here too..please do tell me also if you find any solutions..

Comment: it is very likely your manifest is not setup properly. Post the relevant sections.